# How to filter logcats for my app

Tags: android, android-logcat

The `logcat` in my android does not stop, it keeps displaying the same statements an infinite number of times.This just keeps flowing.

What exactly is the problem? How can I stop these statements from flowing?

One simple solution is to just remove the usb, but I cannot do it since I want to test my app. The `logcat` information is :

```
12-23 12:31:35.316 1264-1281/? I/NetworkIdentity: buildNetworkIdentity:
12-23 12:31:35.316 1264-1281/? I/NetworkIdentity: networkId = suyash
12-23 12:31:35.316 1264-1281/? D/ConnectivityService: getActiveNetworkInfo networkInfo = [type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: "suyash", failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: false]

                                                      [ 12-23 12:31:35.365 23217: 2789 D/         ]
                                                       x = 1.731599,  y = 0.419727,  z = 10.277029
12-23 12:31:35.405 1264-1281/? D/ConnectivityService: allowed status for uid 10185 when rule is 64 (REJECT_ALL): false
12-23 12:31:35.405 1264-1281/? I/NetworkIdentity: buildNetworkIdentity:
12-23 12:31:35.406 1264-1281/? I/NetworkIdentity: networkId = suyash
12-23 12:31:35.406 1264-1281/? D/PowerManagerNotifier: onWakeLockReleased: flags=1, tag="SyncLoopWakeLock", packageName=android, ownerUid=1000, ownerPid=1264, workSource=null
12-23 12:31:35.407 1264-1281/? D/PowerManagerNotifier: onWakeLockAcquired: flags=1, tag="SyncLoopWakeLock", packageName=android, ownerUid=1000, ownerPid=1264, workSource=null
12-23 12:31:35.407 1264-1281/? D/AppOps: startOperation: allowing code 40 uid 1000 package android
12-23 12:31:35.407 1264-1281/? I/NetworkIdentity: buildNetworkIdentity:
12-23 12:31:35.407 1264-1281/? I/NetworkIdentity: networkId = suyash
12-23 12:31:35.407 1264-1281/? D/ConnectivityService: getActiveNetworkInfo networkInfo = [type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: "suyash", failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: false]
12-23 12:31:35.426 1264-4642/? D/ConnectivityService: allowed status for uid 10119 when rule is 0 (NONE): true
12-23 12:31:35.426 1264-4642/? I/NetworkIdentity: buildNetworkIdentity:
12-23 12:31:35.426 1264-4642/? I/NetworkIdentity: networkId = suyash
12-23 12:31:35.426 1264-4642/? D/ConnectivityService: getActiveNetworkInfo networkInfo = [type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: "suyash", failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: false]

                                                      [ 12-23 12:31:35.499 23217: 2789 D/         ]
                                                       x = 1.735192,  y = 0.393382,  z = 10.232122
12-23 12:31:35.519 1264-1281/? D/ConnectivityService: allowed status for uid 10185 when rule is 64 (REJECT_ALL): false
12-23 12:31:35.519 1264-1281/? I/NetworkIdentity: buildNetworkIdentity:
12-23 12:31:35.519 1264-1281/? I/NetworkIdentity: networkId = suyash
12-23 12:31:35.520 1264-1281/? D/PowerManagerNotifier: onWakeLockReleased: flags=1, tag="SyncLoopWakeLock", packageName=android, ownerUid=1000, ownerPid=1264, workSource=null
12-23 12:31:35.521 1264-1281/? D/PowerManagerNotifier: onWakeLockAcquired: flags=1, tag="SyncLoopWakeLock", packageName=android, ownerUid=1000, ownerPid=1264, workSource=null
12-23 12:31:35.521 1264-1281/? D/AppOps: startOperation: allowing code 40 uid 1000 package android
12-23 12:31:35.521 1264-1281/? I/NetworkIdentity: buildNetworkIdentity:
12-23 12:31:35.521 1264-1281/? I/NetworkIdentity: networkId = suyash
12-23 12:31:35.521 1264-1281/? D/ConnectivityService: getActiveNetworkInfo networkInfo = [type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: "suyash", failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: false]

                                                      [ 12-23 12:31:35.566 23217: 2789 D/         ]
                                                       x = 1.705254,  y = 0.369432,  z = 10.281818
12-23 12:31:35.623 1264-1273/? I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 47486(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 22(4MB) LOS objects, 7% free, 49MB/53MB, paused 2.797ms total 167.415ms

                                      [ 12-23 12:31:35.632 23217: 2789 D/         ]
                                       x = 1.659749,  y = 0.378413,  z = 10.238110
12-23 12:31:35.635 1264-1281/? D/ConnectivityService: allowed status for uid 10185 when rule is 64 (REJECT_ALL): false
12-23 12:31:35.636 1264-1281/? I/NetworkIdentity: buildNetworkIdentity:
12-23 12:31:35.636 1264-1281/? I/NetworkIdentity: networkId = suyash
12-23 12:31:35.637 1264-1281/? D/PowerManagerNotifier: onWakeLockReleased: flags=1, tag="SyncLoopWakeLock", packageName=android, ownerUid=1000, ownerPid=1264, workSource=null
12-23 12:31:35.637 1264-1281/? D/PowerManagerNotifier: onWakeLockAcquired: flags=1, tag="SyncLoopWakeLock", packageName=android, ownerUid=1000, ownerPid=1264, workSource=null
12-23 12:31:35.638 1264-1281/? D/AppOps: startOperation: allowing code 40 uid 1000 package android
12-23 12:31:35.638 1264-1281/? I/NetworkIdentity: buildNetworkIdentity:
12-23 12:31:35.638 1264-1281/? I/NetworkIdentity: networkId = suyash
12-23 12:31:35.638 1264-1281/? D/ConnectivityService: getActiveNetworkInfo networkInfo = [type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: "suyash", failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: false]

                                                      [ 12-23 12:31:35.699 23217: 2789 D/         ]
                                                       x = 1.730402,  y = 0.385598,  z = 10.245295
12-23 12:31:35.736 1264-1281/? D/ConnectivityService: allowed status for uid 10185 when rule is 64 (REJECT_ALL): false
12-23 12:31:35.736 1264-1281/? I/NetworkIdentity: buildNetworkIdentity:
12-23 12:31:35.736 1264-1281/? I/NetworkIdentity: networkId = suyash
12-23 12:31:35.737 1264-1281/? D/PowerManagerNotifier: onWakeLockReleased: flags=1, tag="SyncLoopWakeLock", packageName=android, ownerUid=1000, ownerPid=1264, workSource=null
12-23 12:31:35.739 1264-1281/? D/PowerManagerNotifier: onWakeLockAcquired: flags=1, tag="SyncLoopWakeLock", packageName=android, ownerUid=1000, ownerPid=1264, workSource=null
12-23 12:31:35.740 1264-1281/? D/AppOps: startOperation: allowing code 40 uid 1000 package android
12-23 12:31:35.740 1264-1281/? I/NetworkIdentity: buildNetworkIdentity:
12-23 12:31:35.740 1264-1281/? I/NetworkIdentity: networkId = suyash
12-23 12:31:35.740 1264-1281/? D/ConnectivityService: getActiveNetworkInfo networkInfo = [type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: "suyash", failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: false]

                                                      [ 12-23 12:31:35.766 23217: 2789 D/         ]
                                                       x = 1.696871,  y = 0.426912,  z = 10.377620
12-23 12:31:35.788 314-707/? W/MAL-RDS:  (    rum_wsl_poll_wpainfo,  750) [RDS-W][RUM][rum_wsl_poll_wpainfo][RDS] ctrl_sock FD_ISSET error(0)
12-23 12:31:35.788 314-707/? I/MAL-RDS:  (  rum_update_wifi_status, 1055) [RDS-I][RUM][rum_update_wifi_status][RDS] get rssi<0> snr<60> plr<0>
12-23 12:31:35.788 314-707/? I/MAL-RDS:  (   rum_send_event_entity,   81) [RDS-I][RDS][RUM][rum_send_event_entity] send event 9005 to 906
12-23 12:31:35.788 314-707/? I/MAL-RDS:  (   rum_send_event_entity,   81) [RDS-I][RDS][RUM][rum_send_event_entity] send event 9005 to 907
12-23 12:31:35.788 314-737/? I/MAL-RDS:  (  rds_ru_wifi_status_ind, 1662) [RDS-I][RU][EVENT_RUM_RU_WIFI_STATUS_REQ] fgwifi_en:1(no use) i4wifirssi:0x0 i4wifisnr:0x3c sim_id:1
12-23 12:31:35.788 314-737/? I/MAL-RDS:  (  rds_ru_ims_vops_update, 6058) [RDS-I][RU][rds_ru_ims_vops_update][RDS IMS]IMS VOPS IE is Disabled, Update to RPL<0>:(254,254), <1>:(254,254), <2>:(254,254)
12-23 12:31:35.789 314-737/? I/MAL-RDS:  (          rds_ru_rpl_gen, 6343) [RDS-I][RU][rds_ru_rpl_gen][RDS] Current policy: fgimsolte_en<1>, fgwfc_en<0>, erdspolicy<3>,||Threshold i4wifirssih<-75>, i4wifirssil<-85>, i4wifirssih_ho<-78>, i4wifirssil_ho<-88>, i4wifisnrh<10>, i4wifisnrl<6>||Threshold i4ltersrph<-106>, i4ltersrpm<-111>, i4ltersrpl<-116>, i4ltersrqh<5>, i4ltersrqm<3>, i4ltersrql<1>||Threshold i43grscph<-85>, i43grscpl<-105>, i42grssih<-83>, i42grssil<-103>, i4lterssnrl<-3>, i43gecnol<-15>||current rds ru status: i4wifirssi<-100>, i4wifisnr<9999>, i4ltersrp<-141>, i4ltersrq<0>, u4active_ran<1>, i4lterssnr<-50>, i43gecno<-24>, u4sig_reg_status<0>||current wifi backhaul : rtp_plr<0>, rtp_jitter<0>, ping_ind<0>||pcscf acc stat : volte<1>, wfc<1> || wifi acc_ctrl:<0>, || current MD stat : MD1 roam <0>, ||Call stat : IR92<0>, IR94<0>, SMS over IP<0> , sim<1>
12-23 12:31:35.789 314-737/? I/MAL-RDS:  (          rds_ru_rpl_gen, 6360) [RDS-I][RU][RDS IMS/MMS][rds_ru_rpl_gen][OP-0] Ori:(254,254)/(255,255) New:(254,254)/(255,255)||[RU][RDS IMS/MMS WIFI]Ori:(254,254)/(255,255) New:(254,254)/(255,255)||[RU][RDS IMS/MMS CELL]Ori:(254,254)/(255,255) New:(254,254)/(255,255) , sim<1>
12-23 12:31:35.789 314-731/? I/MAL-RDS:  (  rds_ru_wifi_status_ind, 1662) [RDS-I][RU][EVENT_RUM_RU_WIFI_STATUS_REQ] fgwifi_en:1(no use) i4wifirssi:0x0 i4wifisnr:0x3c sim_id:0
12-23 12:31:35.789 314-707/? I/MAL-RDS:  (         rum_get_netstat,  975) [RDS-I][RUM][rum_get_netstat] netstat <thrghpt, pkterrt>, wifi <2523, 0%>, mobile <0, 0%>
12-23 12:31:35.789 314-707/? I/MAL-RDS:  (   rum_send_event_entity,   81) [RDS-I][RDS][RUM][rum_send_event_entity] send event 9706 to 906
12-23 12:31:35.789 314-707/? I/MAL-RDS:  (   rum_send_event_entity,   81) [RDS-I][RDS][RUM][rum_send_event_entity] send event 9706 to 907
12-23 12:31:35.789 314-731/? I/MAL-RDS:  (          rds_ru_rpl_gen, 6343) [RDS-I][RU][rds_ru_rpl_gen][RDS] Current policy: fgimsolte_en<1>, fgwfc_en<0>, erdspolicy<3>,||Threshold i4wifirssih<-75>, i4wifirssil<-85>, i4wifirssih_ho<-78>, i4wifirssil_ho<-88>, i4wifisnrh<10>, i4wifisnrl<6>||Threshold i4ltersrph<-106>, i4ltersrpm<-111>, i4ltersrpl<-116>, i4ltersrqh<5>, i4ltersrqm<3>, i4ltersrql<1>||Threshold i43grscph<-85>, i43grscpl<-105>, i42grssih<-83>, i42grssil<-103>, i4lterssnrl<-3>, i43gecnol<-15>||current rds ru status: i4wifirssi<-100>, i4wifisnr<9999>, i4ltersrp<-123>, i4ltersrq<1>, u4active_ran<1>, i4lterssnr<-29>, i43gecno<-24>, u4sig_reg_status<7>||current wifi backhaul : rtp_plr<0>, rtp_jitter<0>, ping_ind<0>||pcscf acc stat : volte<1>, wfc<1> || wifi acc_ctrl:<0>, || current MD stat : MD1 roam <1>, ||Call stat : IR92<0>, IR94<0>, SMS over IP<0> , sim<0>
12-23 12:31:35.789 314-707/? I/MAL-RDS:  (   rum_send_event_entity,   81) [RDS-I][RDS][RUM][rum_send_event_entity] send event 9029 to 906
12-23 12:31:35.789 314-731/? I/MAL-RDS:  (          rds_ru_rpl_gen, 6360) [RDS-I][RU][RDS IMS/MMS][rds_ru_rpl_gen][OP-0] Ori:(254,254)/(255,255) New:(254,254)/(255,255)||[RU][RDS IMS/MMS WIFI]Ori:(254,254)/(255,255) New:(254,254)/(255,255)||[RU][RDS IMS/MMS CELL]Ori:(254,254)/(255,255) New:(254,254)/(255,255) , sim<0>
12-23 12:31:35.789 314-707/? I/MAL-RDS:  (rds_rum_rum_wsl_timer_ti, 1072) [RDS-I][RUM][rds_rum_rum_wsl_timer_timeout_req][RDS] rds_rum_rum_wsl_timer_timeout_req: prcontext->i4wifi_rssi = 0, prcontext->i4wifi_snr = 60
12-23 12:31:35.789 314-731/? I/MAL-RDS:  (    ru_send_event_entity,  396) [RDS-I][RDS][RU][ru_send_event_entity] send event 9016 to 1034 with ret(0)
12-23 12:31:35.789 1655-1723/? I/MFI-Conn:  (     mfia_task_bootstrap,  910) mfia_task_bootstrap(): an event EVENT_MFI_RU_WIFI_NET_STAT_IND(9016) incoming from FD 47!!
12-23 12:31:35.790 1655-1720/? I/MFI-RDS:  (             rds_urc_hdl,  509) [RDS][rds_urc_hdl] RCV Event: 9016 
12-23 12:31:35.790 314-737/? I/MAL-RDS:  (    ru_send_event_entity,  396) [RDS-I][RDS][RU][ru_send_event_entity] send event 9016 to 1034 with ret(0)
12-23 12:31:35.790 1655-1723/? I/MFI-Conn:  (     mfia_task_bootstrap,  910) mfia_task_bootstrap(): an event EVENT_MFI_RU_WIFI_NET_STAT_IND(9016) incoming from FD 47!!
12-23 12:31:35.790 1655-1720/? I/MFI-RDS:  (             rds_urc_hdl,  509) [RDS][rds_urc_hdl] RCV Event: 9016 
12-23 12:31:35.789 314-731/? I/MAL-RDS:  (rds_ru_mdmngr_atrsp_hndl, 2982) [RDS-I][RDS][RU][rds_ru_mdmngr_atrsp_hndl] get AT resp: +ECSQ: 0,18,1,1,1,-82,-491,7,-28,5

                                        OK
                                        , priv: 0xe9117fc8, at_type: 5 sim: 0
12-23 12:31:35.790 314-731/? I/MAL-RDS:  (rds_ru_mdmngr_atrsp_hndl, 3047) [RDS-I][RDS][RU][rds_ru_mdmngr_atrsp_hndl] Update 3GPP STATUS rsrp<-123> rsrq<0> rssnr<-28> ecno<5> sig_regstat<7>  regstat<8> sim<0>
12-23 12:31:35.790 314-731/? I/MAL-RDS:  (    ru_send_event_entity,  396) [RDS-I][RDS][RU][ru_send_event_entity] send event 9006 to 906 with ret(0)
12-23 12:31:35.790 314-731/? I/MAL-RDS:  (  rds_ru_3gpp_status_ind, 1717) [RDS-I][RU][EVENT_RU_DM_3GPP_STATUS_IND] i4ltersrp:-123, i4ltersrq:0, i4lterssnr:-28, i43gecno:5, u43gpp_status:0x8, sim_id:0
12-23 12:31:35.790 314-731/? E/MAL-RDS:  (  rds_ru_3gpp_status_ind, 1759) [RDS-E][RU][EVENT_RU_DM_3GPP_STATUS_IND] Invalid u43gpp_status:0x8 sim:0
12-23 12:31:35.790 314-731/? I/MAL-RDS:  (  ru_ims_ctrl_send_atcmd, 1353) [RDS-I][RU][ru_ims_ctrl_send_atcmd] (old:new) => wfc(0:0), volte(1:1), video(1:1), opid(0) | system property(0,1,1)
12-23 12:31:35.791 314-731/? I/MAL-RDS:  (          rds_ru_rpl_gen, 6343) [RDS-I][RU][rds_ru_rpl_gen][RDS] Current policy: fgimsolte_en<1>, fgwfc_en<0>, erdspolicy<3>,||Threshold i4wifirssih<-75>, i4wifirssil<-85>, i4wifirssih_ho<-78>, i4wifirssil_ho<-88>, i4wifisnrh<10>, i4wifisnrl<6>||Threshold i4ltersrph<-106>, i4ltersrpm<-111>, i4ltersrpl<-116>, i4ltersrqh<5>, i4ltersrqm<3>, i4ltersrql<1>||Threshold i43grscph<-85>, i43grscpl<-105>, i42grssih<-83>, i42grssil<-103>, i4lterssnrl<-3>, i43gecnol<-15>||current rds ru status: i4wifirssi<-100>, i4wifisnr<9999>, i4ltersrp<-123>, i4ltersrq<0>, u4active_ran<1>, i4lterssnr<-28>, i43gecno<-24>, u4sig_reg_status<7>||current wifi backhaul : rtp_plr<0>, rtp_jitter<0>, ping_ind<0>||pcscf acc stat : volte<1>, wfc<1> || wifi acc_ctrl:<0>, || current MD stat : MD1 roam <1>, ||Call stat : IR92<0>, IR94<0>, SMS over IP<0> , sim<0>
12-23 12:31:35.791 314-731/? I/MAL-RDS:  (          rds_ru_rpl_gen, 6360) [RDS-I][RU][RDS IMS/MMS][rds_ru_rpl_gen][OP-0] Ori:(254,254)/(255,255) New:(254,254)/(255,255)||[RU][RDS IMS/MMS WIFI]Ori:(254,254)/(255,255) New:(254,254)/(255,255)||[RU][RDS IMS/MMS CELL]Ori:(254,254)/(255,255) New:(254,254)/(255,255) , sim<0>
12-23 12:31:35.791 314-707/? I/MAL-RDS:  (     rum_wsl_connect_wpa,  611) [RDS-I][RUM][rum_wsl_connect_wpa][RDS] wpa socket try to connect wpa(0)
12-23 12:31:35.792 314-707/? I/MAL-RDS:  (     rum_wsl_connect_wpa,  675) [RDS-I][RUM][rum_wsl_connect_wpa][RDS]wpa socket connected to /data/misc/wifi/sockets/wlan0 
12-23 12:31:35.809 314-707/? I/MAL-RDS:  (  rum_update_wifi_status, 1055) [RDS-I][RUM][rum_update_wifi_status][RDS] get rssi<-62> snr<9999> plr<0>
12-23 12:31:35.809 314-707/? I/MAL-RDS:  (   rum_send_event_entity,   81) [RDS-I][RDS][RUM][rum_send_event_entity] send event 9005 to 906
12-23 12:31:35.809 314-707/? I/MAL-RDS:  (   rum_send_event_entity,   81) [RDS-I][RDS][RUM][rum_send_event_entity] send event 9005 to 907
12-23 12:31:35.810 314-707/? I/MAL-RDS:  (         rum_get_netstat,  975) [RDS-I][RUM][rum_get_netstat] netstat <thrghpt, pkterrt>, wifi <2523, 0%>, mobile <0, 0%>
12-23 12:31:35.810 314-707/? I/MAL-RDS:  (   rum_send_event_entity,   81) [RDS-I][RDS][RUM][rum_send_event_entity] send event 9706 to 906
12-23 12:31:35.810 314-707/? I/MAL-RDS:  (   rum_send_event_entity,   81) [RDS-I][RDS][RUM][rum_send_event_entity] send event 9706 to 907
12-23 12:31:35.810 314-731/? I/MAL-RDS:  (  rds_ru_wifi_status_ind, 1662) [RDS-I][RU][EVENT_RUM_RU_WIFI_STATUS_REQ] fgwifi_en:1(no use) i4wifirssi:0xffffffc2 i4wifisnr:0x270f sim_id:0
12-23 12:31:35.810 314-731/? I/MAL-RDS:  (          rds_ru_rpl_gen, 6343) [RDS-I][RU][rds_ru_rpl_gen][RDS] Current policy: fgimsolte_en<1>, fgwfc_en<0>, erdspolicy<3>,||Threshold i4wifirssih<-75>, i4wifirssil<-85>, i4wifirssih_ho<-78>, i4wifirssil_ho<-88>, i4wifisnrh<10>, i4wifisnrl<6>||Threshold i4ltersrph<-106>, i4ltersrpm<-111>, i4ltersrpl<-116>, i4ltersrqh<5>, i4ltersrqm<3>, i4ltersrql<1>||Threshold i43grscph<-85>, i43grscpl<-105>, i42grssih<-83>, i42grssil<-103>, i4lterssnrl<-3>, i43gecnol<-15>||current rds ru status: i4wifirssi<-62>, i4wifisnr<9999>, i4ltersrp<-123>, i4ltersrq<0>, u4active_ran<1>, i4lterssnr<-28>, i43gecno<-24>, u4sig_reg_status<7>||current wifi backhaul : rtp_plr<0>, rtp_jitter<0>, ping_ind<0>||pcscf acc stat : volte<1>, wfc<1> || wifi acc_ctrl:<0>, || current MD stat : MD1 roam <1>, ||Call stat : IR92<0>, IR94<0>, SMS over IP<0> , sim<0>
12-23 12:31:35.810 314-731/? I/MAL-RDS:  (          rds_ru_rpl_gen, 6360) [RDS-I][RU][RDS IMS/MMS][rds_ru_rpl_gen][OP-0] Ori:(254,254)/(255,255) New:(254,254)/(255,255)||[RU][RDS IMS/MMS WIFI]Ori:(254,254)/(255,255) New:(254,254)/(255,255)||[RU][RDS IMS/MMS CELL]Ori:(254,254)/(255,255) New:(254,254)/(255,255) , sim<0>
12-23 12:31:35.810 314-731/? I/MAL-RDS:  (    ru_send_event_entity,  396) [RDS-I][RDS][RU][ru_send_event_entity] send event 9016 to 1034 with ret(0)
12-23 12:31:35.811 1655-1723/? I/MFI-Conn:  (     mfia_task_bootstrap,  910) mfia_task_bootstrap(): an event EVENT_MFI_RU_WIFI_NET_STAT_IND(9016) incoming from FD 47!!
12-23 12:31:35.811 1655-1720/? I/MFI-RDS:  (             rds_urc_hdl,  509) [RDS][rds_urc_hdl] RCV Event: 9016 
12-23 12:31:35.812 314-737/? I/MAL-RDS:  (  rds_ru_wifi_status_ind, 1662) [RDS-I][RU][EVENT_RUM_RU_WIFI_STATUS_REQ] fgwifi_en:1(no use) i4wifirssi:0xffffffc2 i4wifisnr:0x270f sim_id:1
12-23 12:31:35.812 314-737/? I/MAL-RDS:  (  rds_ru_ims_vops_update, 6058) [RDS-I][RU][rds_ru_ims_vops_update][RDS IMS]IMS VOPS IE is Disabled, Update to RPL<0>:(254,254), <1>:(254,254), <2>:(254,254)
12-23 12:31:35.812 314-737/? I/MAL-RDS:  (          rds_ru_rpl_gen, 6343) [RDS-I][RU][rds_ru_rpl_gen][RDS] Current policy: fgimsolte_en<1>, fgwfc_en<0>, erdspolicy<3>,||Threshold i4wifirssih<-75>, i4wifirssil<-85>, i4wifirssih_ho<-78>, i4wifirssil_ho<-88>, i4wifisnrh<10>, i4wifisnrl<6>||Threshold i4ltersrph<-106>, i4ltersrpm<-111>, i4ltersrpl<-116>, i4ltersrqh<5>, i4ltersrqm<3>, i4ltersrql<1>||Threshold i43grscph<-85>, i43grscpl<-105>, i42grssih<-83>, i42grssil<-103>, i4lterssnrl<-3>, i43gecnol<-15>||current rds ru status: i4wifirssi<-62>, i4wifisnr<9999>, i4ltersrp<-141>, i4ltersrq<0>, u4active_ran<1>, i4lterssnr<-50>, i43gecno<-24>, u4sig_reg_status<0>||current wifi backhaul : rtp_plr<0>, rtp_jitter<0>, ping_ind<0>||pcscf acc stat : volte<1>, wfc<1> || wifi acc_ctrl:<0>, || current MD stat : MD1 roam <0>, ||Call stat : IR92<0>, IR94<0>, SMS over IP<0> , sim<1>
12-23 12:31:35.812 314-737/? I/MAL-RDS:  (          rds_ru_rpl_gen, 6360) [RDS-I][RU][RDS IMS/MMS][rds_ru_rpl_gen][OP-0] Ori:(254,254)/(255,255) New:(254,254)/(255,255)||[RU][RDS IMS/MMS WIFI]Ori:(254,254)/(255,255) New:(254,254)/(255,255)||[RU][RDS IMS/MMS CELL]Ori:(254,254)/(255,255) New:(254,254)/(255,255) , sim<1>
12-23 12:31:35.812 314-737/? I/MAL-RDS:  (    ru_send_event_entity,  396) [RDS-I][RDS][RU][ru_send_event_entity] send event 9016 to 1034 with ret(0)
12-23 12:31:35.813 1655-1723/? I/MFI-Conn:  (     mfia_task_bootstrap,  910) mfia_task_bootstrap(): an event EVENT_MFI_RU_WIFI_NET_STAT_IND(9016) incoming from FD 47!!
12-23 12:31:35.813 1655-1720/? I/MFI-RDS:  (             rds_urc_hdl,  509) [RDS][rds_urc_hdl] RCV Event: 9016 


                                          [ 12-23 12:31:35.833 23217: 2789 D/         ]
                                           x = 1.774111,  y = 0.368234,  z = 10.275831
12-23 12:31:35.871 1264-1281/? D/ConnectivityService: allowed status for uid 10185 when rule is 64 (REJECT_ALL): false
12-23 12:31:35.871 1264-1281/? I/NetworkIdentity: buildNetworkIdentity:
12-23 12:31:35.871 1264-1281/? I/NetworkIdentity: networkId = suyash
12-23 12:31:35.872 1264-1281/? D/PowerManagerNotifier: onWakeLockReleased: flags=1, tag="SyncLoopWakeLock", packageName=android, ownerUid=1000, ownerPid=1264, workSource=null
12-23 12:31:35.872 1264-1281/? D/PowerManagerNotifier: onWakeLockAcquired: flags=1, tag="SyncLoopWakeLock", packageName=android, ownerUid=1000, ownerPid=1264, workSource=null
12-23 12:31:35.873 1264-1281/? D/AppOps: startOperation: allowing code 40 uid 1000 package android
12-23 12:31:35.873 1264-1281/? I/NetworkIdentity: buildNetworkIdentity:
12-23 12:31:35.873 1264-1281/? I/NetworkIdentity: networkId = suyash
12-23 12:31:35.873 1264-1281/? D/ConnectivityService: getActiveNetworkInfo networkInfo = [type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: "suyash", failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: false]
12-23 12:31:35.882 30385-30385/? D/WebView: evaluateJavascript=AFMA_updateActiveView({"units":[{"afmaVersion":"afma-sdk-a-v11951448.11020000.1","activeViewJSON":{"click_string":"Bry7Clfw9WtiqLsyWrQHR3qXIBwAAAAAQATgByAEDwAIC4AIAyAOZBOAEAaAGFNIIBQiAIRAB","is_active_view_immediate_enabled":true,"activeview_cpm_urls":[],"active_experiment_ids":"","activeview_cid":"CAASEuRoe3P7cX9YHE1uszSHknwmcg","active_view_url_prefix":"https:\/\/pagead2.googlesyndication.com\/pcs\/activeview?xai=AKAOjsteyzi-iiWV9w5iI9tVxHodiYIdnEoSP2r9TLk3piKI9xjBEd2QE8URrxGDeYfIrok-KvweXMI9N2teNHNW0V4Bx5VevWDsbKo&sig=Cg0ArKJSzEv1pHw4Tb9XEAE"},"timestamp":46929993,"adFormat":"360x26_as","hashCode":"4bc51b20-17dd-420f-a073-b64dcac44812","isMraid":false,"isStopped":false,"isPaused":false,"isNative":false,"isScreenOn":true,"appMuted":false,"appVolume":1,"deviceVolume":0.6666666865348816,"windowVisibility":8,"isAttachedToWindow":false,"viewBox":{"top":0,"bottom":592,"left":0,"right":360},"adBox":{"top":0,"bottom":26,"left":0,"right":360},"globalVisibleBox":{"top":0,"bottom":26,"left":0,"right":360},"globalVisibleBoxVisible":true,"localVisibleBox":{"top":0,"bottom":26,"left":0,"right":360},"localVisibleBoxVisible":true,"hitBox":{"top":0,"bottom":26,"left":0,"right":360},"screenDensity":3,"isVisible":false}]});

                                            [ 12-23 12:31:35.899 23217: 2789 D/         ]
                                             x = 1.700464,  y = 0.382604,  z = 10.227931


                                            [ 12-23 12:31:35.966 23217: 2789 D/         ]
                                             x = 1.782493,  y = 0.375419,  z = 10.257869
12-23 12:31:35.981 1264-1464/? D/ConnectivityService: allowed status for uid 10119 when rule is 0 (NONE): true
12-23 12:31:35.981 1264-1464/? I/NetworkIdentity: buildNetworkIdentity:
12-23 12:31:35.981 1264-1464/? I/NetworkIdentity: networkId = suyash
12-23 12:31:35.982 1264-1464/? D/ConnectivityService: getActiveNetworkInfo networkInfo = [type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: "suyash", failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: false]
12-23 12:31:35.990 1264-1281/? D/ConnectivityService: allowed status for uid 10185 when rule is 64 (REJECT_ALL): false
12-23 12:31:35.990 1264-1281/? I/NetworkIdentity: buildNetworkIdentity:
12-23 12:31:35.990 1264-1281/? I/NetworkIdentity: networkId = suyash
12-23 12:31:35.998 1264-1281/? D/PowerManagerNotifier: onWakeLockReleased: flags=1, tag="SyncLoopWakeLock", packageName=android, ownerUid=1000, ownerPid=1264, workSource=null
12-23 12:31:35.999 1264-1281/? D/PowerManagerNotifier: onWakeLockAcquired: flags=1, tag="SyncLoopWakeLock", packageName=android, ownerUid=1000, ownerPid=1264, workSource=null
12-23 12:31:35.999 1264-1281/? D/AppOps: startOperation: allowing code 40 uid 1000 package android
12-23 12:31:35.999 1264-1281/? I/NetworkIdentity: buildNetworkIdentity:
12-23 12:31:36.000 1264-1281/? I/NetworkIdentity: networkId = suyash
12-23 12:31:36.007 1264-1281/? D/ConnectivityService: getActiveNetworkInfo networkInfo = [type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: "suyash", failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: false]

                                                      [ 12-23 12:31:36.033 23217: 2789 D/         ]
                                                       x = 1.717229,  y = 0.401765,  z = 10.235116


                                                      [ 12-23 12:31:36.100 23217: 2789 D/         ]
                                                       x = 1.715433,  y = 0.344883,  z = 10.302775
12-23 12:31:36.116 1264-1281/? D/ConnectivityService: allowed status for uid 10185 when rule is 64 (REJECT_ALL): false
12-23 12:31:36.116 1264-1281/? I/NetworkIdentity: buildNetworkIdentity:
12-23 12:31:36.117 1264-1281/? I/NetworkIdentity: networkId = suyash
12-23 12:31:36.117 1264-1281/? D/PowerManagerNotifier: onWakeLockReleased: flags=1, tag="SyncLoopWakeLock", packageName=android, ownerUid=1000, ownerPid=1264, workSource=null
12-23 12:31:36.117 1264-1281/? D/PowerManagerNotifier: onWakeLockAcquired: flags=1, tag="SyncLoopWakeLock", packageName=android, ownerUid=1000, ownerPid=1264, workSource=null
12-23 12:31:36.117 1264-1281/? D/AppOps: startOperation: allowing code 40 uid 1000 package android
12-23 12:31:36.118 1264-1281/? I/NetworkIdentity: buildNetworkIdentity:
12-23 12:31:36.118 1264-1281/? I/NetworkIdentity: networkId = suyash
12-23 12:31:36.118 1264-1281/? D/ConnectivityService: getActiveNetworkInfo networkInfo = [type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: "suyash", failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: false]

                                                      [ 12-23 12:31:36.166 23217: 2789 D/         ]
                                                       x = 1.735192,  y = 0.409548,  z = 10.257869
12-23 12:31:36.213 1264-1281/? D/ConnectivityService: allowed status for uid 10185 when rule is 64 (REJECT_ALL): false
12-23 12:31:36.214 1264-1281/? I/NetworkIdentity: buildNetworkIdentity:
12-23 12:31:36.214 1264-1281/? I/NetworkIdentity: networkId = suyash
12-23 12:31:36.214 1264-1281/? D/PowerManagerNotifier: onWakeLockReleased: flags=1, tag="SyncLoopWakeLock", packageName=android, ownerUid=1000, ownerPid=1264, workSource=null
12-23 12:31:36.216 1264-1281/? D/PowerManagerNotifier: onWakeLockAcquired: flags=1, tag="SyncLoopWakeLock", packageName=android, ownerUid=1000, ownerPid=1264, workSource=null
12-23 12:31:36.216 1264-1281/? D/AppOps: startOperation: allowing code 40 uid 1000 package android
```

Comment: you should filter your process of the app .in this case you will be getting your app logs.

Comment: Select **Show only selected application** from the drop-down menu on the right most side of logcat window!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the top right corner of the log cat window, there is a filer config combo box. Select or create a filter of your own to filter out relevant logs.

You can add filter in your Logcat, and mention all the classes whose logs you want to discard.

Answer (score 1):

Have you selected following option in your logcat:

[image]

or You can **restart your logcat.**

or You can filter by **your project package name.**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be solved by restarting logcat. you can restart your logcat by pressing restart button placed on left pannel in logcat window.

[image]